# Blender VSE 180 VR export

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, video, vr

I have MP4 files from Insta360 Evo camera that I want to edit, combine and export using Blender VSE. The editing is no problem - but the exports are not working when I then view them thru the Meta Quest 2 usking Skybox viewer app (not side by side stereopsis). I've tried every permutation in blender with rendering the file. I'm playing around now with injecting metadata back into the rendered files. **In summary - I have pre-existing 180VR footage, just want to edit it and export it using Blender VSE**. People can do it in other VSEs - is it possible here? Thanks